# Interpreting information on Decision Tree nodes from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

What is the interpretation of the "value" of each node of a decision tree created with sklearn?  I thought the numbers in "value" were supposed to add up to "samples," but as you can see from the image, mine do not.  (That is a picture of just one node, but they are all like that.)  I know this must have something to do with the class weights I applied, because when I make a decision tree without weighting, the values add up to the samples.  But since 10% of my data is a '1' and 90% is a '0' for the target variable, I assigned class weights of {0:0:10, 1:0.90} to compensate for the imbalance in the data. Is it supposed to be the other way around?

[image]

Please help me understand how to interpret each node in the decision tree.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpretation of `value` is just the sum of the samples times their respective weights.

We can infer in your case that the 254.5 is the class weighted as `0.1`. So, that means we have 2545 samples of that class (because `2545 * 0.1 = 254.5`). Similarly, `20 * 0.9 = 18`, so we have 20 samples of the class weighted at 0.9. Together, the result is 2545 + 20 = 2565 samples, which is equal to your samples.

In the default case, sample weights are all 1, meaning `value` will sum to the number of samples.

I would recommend using integer weights `{0:1, 1:9}`, as you should avoid using floats unless necessary.